# convert list of object into a map of <String,Map<String,Integer>> java8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

hello I have a list of objects my object have three fields

```
class MyObject{
   String x;
   String y;
   int  z;
   //getters n setters
}
```

I need to convert this list into a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`

that is like this:
`{x1:{y1:z1,y2:z2,y3:z3},x2{y4:z4,y5:z5}}` format I want to do this in Java 8 which I think I am relatively new to it.

I have tried the following :

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map=list.stream().
                collect(Collectors.
                        groupingBy(MyObject::getX,list.stream().
                                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getY,
                                        Collectors.summingInt(MyObject::getZ)))));
```

this does not even compile. help is much appreciated

Comment: Please provide a sample input, is not clear how you get all those y's and z's out of a single x

Comment: You shouldn't re-use your stream like that, nor should you need too.  I don't think you problem is a good match for Streams, as I think you are trying to take the first two elements and map them to ```MyObject.x``` and the third and forth elements and map them using the second elements x value.  It might be possible with a custom collector, but you are manipulating a lot of state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by chaining two `groupingBy` `Collector`s and one `summingInt` `Collector`:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.
                    groupingBy(MyObject::getX,
                               Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getY,
                                                     Collectors.summingInt(MyObject::getZ))));
```

I hope I got the logic you wanted right.

When adding to the input `List` the following :

```
list.add(new MyObject("A","B",10));
list.add(new MyObject("A","C",5));
list.add(new MyObject("A","B",15));
list.add(new MyObject("B","C",10));
list.add(new MyObject("A","C",12));
```

You get an output `Map` of :

```
{A={B=25, C=17}, B={C=10}}
```